# Problem with for loops, trying to make a specific pattern

Tags: c

I am trying to make a V shape. it is almost perfect but i cannot change the ammount of spaces i need to print by changing variables l and r in the very end. im new to programming and im at my wits end here. it should logically work, right?

[shape im trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTMEg.jpg)

[what i actually get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrRJ6.png)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int l=0,r=17,y=9,x=0,z=0;

for(z=0;z<y;z++){


    for(x=0;x<l;x++){
        printf(" "); //first space
    }
    printf("****");

    for(x=0;x<r;x++){
        printf(" "); //second space
    }
    printf("****");
    printf("\n");
    l+1;
    r-2;
}
}
```

Comment: Try to enable warnings in your compiler usually with `-Wall` then it should be clear. Also always enable warnings and most importantly **listen to them**

Comment: `l+1;` and `r-2;` are empty expressions and do nothing. You can safely remove them. Or add a `=` to do an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
l+1;
r-2;
```

does not change the values of l and r.

It should be

```
l = l + 1;
r = r - 2;
```

or

```
l += 1;
r -= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to solving this problem. Your error is here:

```
l+1;
r-2;
```

Think about what happens when you use an operation like `+` or `-`... where does the result go?

Comment: Thank you, i just had to replace l+1 with l=l+1 and r-2 with r=r-2

Answer (score 0):

```
l+1;
r-2;
```

Should both be:

```
l+=1;
r-=2;
```

Here your script with slight modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// v-shape
// gcc -Os -Wall -o 53505746 53505746.c

int main() {

    int l = 0;
    int r = 17;
    int y = 9;
    int x = 0;
    int z = 0;

    for (z=0; z<y; z++) {

        for (x=0; x<l; x++) {
            printf(" "); // first space
        }

        printf("****");

        for (x=0; x<r; x++) {
            printf(" "); // second space
        }

        printf("****");
        printf("\n");
        l += 1;
        r -= 2;

    }

    return 0;
}
```